Role based access control in a Python app deployed in GCP Cloud run
We have a react front end and a python flask backend deployed in GCP cloud run, users are configured in google groups and authenticated via IAP.
Now we want to setup role based access control in our application to allow access to specific pages, we are ok to map the roles in the application but not the user details as we might have to make app changes if you have to add new users.
We explored and figured out that we could create google groups for different roles, use IAM or ACM (Access Context Manger) to set roles to the group and try to retrieve this information in the code and map it to different pages in the application.
Not sure whether we could create custom roles for application in IAM or ACM, also want to understand whether we are in the right direction or if there is any other best approach for application level access control.

IAM is a Google Cloud service designed to authenticate and authorized accounts (user or service) to access to Google Cloud services.
This being said, you can understand that Google has design his own access management system for itself. Not for you.
And you can't use it for your own application. I heard that Google is cooking a new tool to allow you to define and to check customer app authorization, but I have no visibility on the roadmap.
Until then, you have to build your own IAM system, with your own group and role management. Frameworks exist, but it's on your own, Google can't help this right now.
